# Extraer números de un string con REGEX en Python

Tags: python, regex

Con https://pythex.org/ estoy intentando aprender cómo extraer números de un string tipo

> "67 years, 295 days"

Si pongo como pattern esto

```
([\d]+(?= years, ))
```

me marca los años correctamente
pero si pongo esto

```
([\d]+(?= years, ))([\d]+(?=days))
```

no funciona... ¿Por qué no me marca los años y los días?

¿Dónde me equivoco?

Gracias por vuestro tiempo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supongamos que tienes un patrón que simplemente reconoce la expresión "nn years, mm days"

```
"\d+ years, \d+ days"
```

Podemos escribir un código simple para ver si se cumple el patrón o no:

```
a = "67 years, 295 days"
patron_simple = re.compile("\d+ years, \d+ days")
if re.match(patron_simple, a):
    print("match!")
```

Si quieres obtener lo que reconoce una parte dentro del patrón, la encierras entre paréntesis:

```
patron_grupo = re.compile("(\d+) years, (\d+) days")
grupos = re.match(patron_grupo, a)
if grupos:
    print("match!")
    print(grupos[1], grupos[2])
```

Con eso `re.match` retorna un objeto indexable. El indice cero corresponde al string completo, mientras que los indices 1, 2, ... corresponde a cada uno de los elementos capturados por las expresiones entre "( )".

Una tercera forma es recuperar dando nombre. El nombre se escribe "?P<nombre>" por delante del patrón, así:

```
patron_nombre = re.compile("(?P<years>\d+) years, (?P<days>\d+) days")
x=re.match(patron_nombre, a)
if x:
    print("match!")
    print(x["years"], x["days"])
```

Luego puedes recuperar los valores usando el nombre como índice.

Comment: gracias!! Se ve que soy novato hasta para puintuar las respuestas +1

Comment: Buena respuesta: +1

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de usar un ['positive lookahead'](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?= years, )` puedes hacerlo simplemente con:

```
([\d]+) years, ([\d]+) days
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SWPenK/1/)

'Positive lookahead' es un función especial que solo necesitas para casos avanzados.

Comment: muchas gracias!